# How to determine the shape of my input layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, time-series

I am new to Machine Learning and I am currently trying to play around with Tensorflow and Keras.

I have a timeseries windowed dataset with a window size of 128, batch of 32, and 4 features if it matters.

This is in a PrefetchDataset format and when I try to check the shape using .element_spec I get: `(TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, 4, 1), dtype=tf.float64, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 4, 1), dtype=tf.float64, name=None))`

I cannot figure out what the input_shape of my first layer has to be. Can anyone please advise? Thanks

For reference, the method I use:

```
def windowed_dataset(series, window_size, batch_size, shuffle_buffer=None):

    series = tf.expand_dims(series, axis=-1)
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(series)
    dataset = dataset.window(window_size + 1, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
    dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(window_size + 1))

    if shuffle_buffer != None: 
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer)
    dataset = dataset.map(
        lambda window: (window[:-1], window[-1]))
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)

    return dataset
```

Dataset (Dataframe.to_numpy()):

```
array([[0.86749387, 0.87223695, 0.02077445, 0.87542179],
       [0.86755952, 0.87322277, 0.02047971, 0.87551724],
       [0.86749387, 0.8733104 , 0.01424521, 0.8756016 ],
       ...,
       [0.18539916, 0.19000153, 0.00700078, 0.18666753],
       [0.18325455, 0.19000153, 0.        , 0.18610588],
       [0.18636204, 0.19144741, 0.00573779, 0.18572627]])
```

My first layer:

```
Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='causal', input_shape=[None, None, window_size, 4] , activation='relu'),
```

The error:

```
    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_53 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 4 but received input with shape (None, None, 4, 1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_21174/3802335098.py in <module>
----> 1 history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a time series with batch of 32, window of 128 and 4 features, your input shape will be :
(None, Number of batches (Nb), batch size (Bs), window size (Ws), 4)
But What you should specify is:

```
shape=(None, None, Ws, 4)
```

With

```
First None: for Nb (because Nb can vary)
Scd None : for Bs (Because Bs can vary)
```

But I don't understand why you get:

```
shape=(None, None, 4, 1)
```

Comment: Yes, it does not make sense to me that's I am struggling to figure it out. For other exercises I normally would just set the rows and columns but since I am using tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(), it's not working the same

Comment: @CharltonZ1 I just edited my answer. I made a mistake previously.

Comment: I've tried that and so far, I have been getting this error: ``` ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_53 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 4 but received input with shape (None, None, 4, 1) ```

Comment: @CharltonZ1 I advice you to follow what has been done here https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#data_windowing. You will probably get the answer.

Comment: The error you get means probably that your input data is badly formatted. If you can provide more code to inspect what is inside, particularly the one that format your input data.

Comment: Thanks, I've checked out that tutorial and I am able to do this for a dataset with a single feature but nothing I've read so far uses multiple features in the dataset.

Comment: The code presented in the tutorial is also valid for P features. In fact, all will depend on the raw data you provide to the WindowGenerator class. For example, if your raw feature data is a numpy of shape (N, 1) that corespond to your case. And if the shape is (N, P) with P > 1, it correspond to the case of multiple features. Likewise, for labels, you just have to specify more than one label name for the parameter 'label_columns'.